# Setting UWP Target System

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm building an UWP application using Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition.
Everytime I create a new UWP project, I cannot select Target version lower than version 1809. See below pic.

[image: Target version setup dialog]

My problem is, my current windows 10 version is 1803, and when I want to update my windows 10 to 1809, I found that 1809 is somehow not available according to this post in windows forum below:

[Link to forum](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/cant-update-from-1803-to-1809/dc157798-88d7-447c-8d42-cb848ebf3d14)

What happen then, when ever I want to design and preview my UWP app, I cannot render all controllers within the page. Like below pic.

[image: Layout in visual studio]

My question are:

1. How can I resolve this besides waiting for update 1809 avail?
2. Is there anyway I can change the TARGET VERSION of my app? so I can have better experience in coding my app?

Thanks

Comment: run VS2017 setup and under individual components install the older SDKs like 16299, 17134

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have to install older SDK for Min version before you start work.
You can find all versions of it on this page and download them [Windows SDK and emulator archive](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive) .

for example If you want it to be at least compatible with the Windows 10 Anniversary Update then you should download and install SDK (ver. 10.0.14393.795)

Comment: Any results yet?

Comment: Yes ... I install additional SDK and I have 2 target version, thanks ;)